# Laravel : Incorrect embedded image in blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

sorry for the question, but I have an mailing system from a Laravel app that sends a newsletter in HTML format with images on it. I tested by placing the html in blade and embedding the images like this:

```
<?php $message->embed(storage_path().'/images/unnamed.jpg'); ?>
```

Because if I just referenced the location of the image when the html is sent to mail all I'm getting are broken images. However, when I embed the images the mail is incorrect because the images are in different places instead of where they should be. What is the correct way of doing this? Instead of embedding the image should I store it on a cloud storage and just reference it from the html?

Please help, appreciate any advice, solution, or pointers. Thank you very much.

Here is the sample email:
[image: Sample Image where the picture should be in the middle of the html page instead of below the message body]

Comment: *However, when I embed the images the mail is incorrect because the images are in different places instead of where they should be* -- can you elaborate a bit more on this..? i'm curious..

Comment: Have you tried `<img src="{{ url('images/unnamed.jpg') }}" />` directly in the in the template? Or `$message->embed(url('images/unnamed.jpg'))`

Comment: Chineck mo ba console ng mail? Tama ba ang link nun sir?

Comment: I think you have 2 way first add you image in your server and add vhost (if you use apace ) for map to server name with your image path, second you upload your image to cloud and add the url to src tag of image

Comment: @BagusTesa Please see question edits. I've added a sample image you can see from there that the image is below the message body instead of inside it. And the logo from above is missing because it is below the image. Sorry cannot capture the screen.

Comment: @EddyTheDove i tried the first example you mentioned yesterday but I'm getting the incorrect images. Haven't tried the second one yet.

Comment: @LaraBelle, yes sir na verify ko pa sa dev tama naman yung link sa console inisa isa ko pa yung images link pero nung nag send na sa mail nagiba na yung position ng mga image

Comment: @Drew Adorador, just to be sure, did you know that [embed](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Mail/Message.html#method_embed) returns cid? you should use it `<img src=cid:{{ $message->embed(storage_path().'/images/unnamed.jpg') }}/>`, [reference](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/).

Comment: @BagusTesa no i did not know it returns cid. Let me try.

Comment: @BagusTesa the output is still the same.

Comment: hmm, weird the `->embed()` function is indeed put the files as an attachment and returns the `cid` related to the image. the `cid` only to assist which file will be loaded for this placeholder.. something like that.. can you somehow tap into the passed message to the smtp server? using tools like [FakeSMTP](https://github.com/Nilhcem/FakeSMTP) and open it in IE or something where you can take a peek on it's html..? alternatively, you could use @MichalDabrowski answer, using base64 encoded instead of `cid`..

Comment: @AkkapongKajornwongwattana I also tried your solution and uploaded it to a google cloud storage and making it available publicly which return the correct html mail output. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting broken images because it's an external (internet) link to the image. There is no proper way of embedding an image. Every external request is a potential danger and it's block by default by mailing/anti-virus program. The only way to show a picture is to ebed an image directly into HTML. here's an example:
http://www.techerator.com/2011/12/how-to-embed-images-directly-into-your-html/

Comment: I think it worked. although the I have to convert each image to base64. Thanks!!!!